# What is the accountPath input parameter for google scripts tag manager API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tag-manager

The advanced services on Google Apps Scripts allows you run API commands to the tag manager API. However a required input for all of these functions is the `accountPath` input.

Does anyone know what the `accountPath` is? I've tried the account ID in various ways. E.g. the bold in the url `https://tagmanager.google.com/#/container/accounts/`**`3406703695`**`/`

An example of the function call input is below:

```
function createContainerVersion(accountPath) {
 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An accountPath takes the form:

> **accounts/[account-id]**

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, I'm still coming up with the error: Missing formal parameter. 
Do include with quotes or quotes around the words only? Can you advise on the Syntax here?